# What preposition properly collocates with "chuffed"?

Tags: word-usage

As an American of upper middle age, I have noticed younger people using different (and to my ears, wrong) prepositions—for example, "bored of" rather than "bored by."  So, hearing the word *chuffed* in the many British TV shows and movies I watch, I wondered: Is one chuffed by, with, to, or about? Or are any or all of these combinations acceptable?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. There are 2 close votes on your question (not mine), citing lack of research. Try adding a [dictionary definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chuffed) and, if publicly available, some links to scripts of (or even just quotes from) the TV shows to demonstrate the word usage you describe.

Comment: I fell the same way when I hear "come with?" instead of "come with *me/us?"* or "have a coffee" instead of "have a *cup* of coffee". I know it's common now, but it still jars me.

Answer (score 0):

Your best resource for deciding which usage is more prevalent is a *corpus*. You might enjoy playing with the collection of corpora maintained by Mark Davies of Brigham Young. (corpus.byu.edu)

"Chuffed" appears 30 times in the 440 million word Corpus of Contemporary American English. Below are your results. Unfortunately I find only one example of "chuff" + preposition (line 2).

```
1   2015    FIC NewEnglandRev   A   B   C   smiled. " She's the sweetest little thing in the world. " She chuffed Callie's snowsuit and started to turn away. " I can't wait to
2   2014    FIC SewaneeRev  A   B   C   ? God, aye, comes the resounding affirmation, I' d be right chuffed ivith one o f them myself. I' m no made o f money
3   2014    MAG NewStatesman    A   B   C   think that was interesting? # MA Well, I do, I was dead chuffed. Pinker doesn't like the word " empathy " -- he says he went
4   2013    FIC GettysburgRev   A   B   C   and this was the best he could do. The Harley spit and hiccupped and chuffed to life, clearing its throat with every twist of the grip at Gardner's
5   2012    FIC Analog  A   B   C   And Baz wUl get his girlfriend, " Mrs. Chan said. " He's chuffed about that! " # Thelma drew Jones aside, frowning. " Really?
6   2012    FIC Analog  A   B   C   . Maybe the locals just didn't have eyes. # Harvinder and Kim were chuffed. This was the kind of assignment that got you promotions, video deals,
    7   2012    MAG People  A   B   C   royal source tells PEOPLE of the mood inside the palace. " We're really chuffed " -- Brit-speak for giddy -- " but obviously people are anxious about the duchess
    8   2012    MAG Skiing  A   B   C   of regurgitation. Laird appeared to puke up food he ate in 1997. He chuffed every hue of the Technicolor yawn and painted the run below with shredded bits of
    9   2011    FIC AntiochRev  A   B   C   . Her cracked dry lips rose off her square teeth and a happy animal sound chuffed out from the leather of her lungs. # Llewellyn choked on his lemondade.
    10  2011    ACAD    CommunityCare   A   B   C   were paid 25p a mile, " Heywood says. # She was " really chuffed " about the changes " but also proud to work for a private company that
    11  2010    MAG HarpersBazaar   A   B   C   in Turks &; Caicos ($38) Photograph: Butter London Jelly nail polish in Chuffed (right) and Twee ($14 each) Photograph: Anastasia fan Penlope Cruz
    12  2008    FIC Analog  A   B   C   The brown buggers could fight and match a polar bear off the ice. Rariil chuffed. Graashah wasn't that kind of bear. She wouldn't come all the
    13  2007    FIC Analog  A   B   C   n't intend to use it. The man fell to the ground unconscious. Aranead chuffed. He'd seen this reaction before on other planets, with other creatures.
    14  2007    FIC AntiochRev  A   B   C   . Her cracked dry lips rose off her square teeth and a happy animal sound chuffed out from the leather of her lungs. Llewellyn choked on his lemondade. "
    15  2006    FIC Triquarterly    A   B   C   myself-with my briefcase snug at my feet. With a gentle oomph, the train chuffed into motion; frozen bluish fields slipped effortlessly past. It was dusk, and
    16  2006    FIC LiteraryRev A   B   C   else realised, he had made three trips and cleared the lot. He was chuffed. # Afterwards, young Tao could scarcely believe it had happened. He almost
    17  2006    FIC NewYorker   A   B   C   .. whole layout's... super, " and he was " chuffed " to be here. # Wally was in my house in Sea-Clift for five
    18  2006    FIC Bk:CaptiveHeart A   B   C   one wall. In the corner, a hound stirred briefly at the disturbance, chuffed once, then lowered his head to his paws again. But the other denizens
    19  2005    FIC Bk:WithNoOne    A   B   C   Well, you take care with those. Your dad's not going to be chuffed if you fall and break your head. D' you have a helmet or something
    20  2001    FIC Analog  A   B   C   " She smiled. " You're a sharp one. " He felt absurdly chuffed at this praise from a modern. They walked on at a slower pace.
    21  2000    MAG RollingStone    A   B   C   knew how to do was to make a certain noise. But I'm always chuffed when I hear that they still play it, and that people appreciate it.
    22  1999    FIC Analog  A   B   C   I think about what's going on with you. " Justin started to get chuffed, but didn't let it show. A couple of seconds later, he
    23  1999    FIC Analog  A   B   C   there for. " When his older self mentioned the money, Justin forgot how chuffed he was, at least for a little while. " Where'd you get
    24  1998    FIC Bk:FearNothing  A   B   C   'll be all right, " I repeated. The dog regarded me solemnly and chuffed once, almost pityingly, as if he knew I was lying. I opened
    25  1995    FIC FantasySciFi    A   B   C   of detail that made every golden feather a sculpture unto itself. # The teapot chuffed faintly. Vergalant repocketed his kerchief and went to it. # " Indeed,
    26  1995    FIC Bk:TrueBetrayals    A   B   C   reading that boy's face either. Gambler's eyes he's got " He chuffed out smoke, then inhaled deeply, secure in his old friend's interest.
    27  1995    FIC Bk:TrueBetrayals    A   B   C   . " Does she know you've put your brand on her? " Gabe chuffed out smoke, remembering, with fondness, her reaction to his very deliberate public
    28  1992    FIC Omni    A   B   C   see if the horseman had caught her performance. The galloping slowed and the horse chuffed indignantly -- why are we stopping? Why are you reining me in? Shiny
    29  1992    FIC Omni    A   B   C   . Like you've been working out. " # Behind us, the horse chuffed loudly and Epstein whirled fully around to look at it. " What? I
    30  1991    FIC BkSF:TemptationsSt  A   B   C   McKenzie in a clothes drier for too long. The beastie sniffed my feet, chuffed hoarsely a few times, peed on my ankle, and shuffled off.
```